# using EmbeddedWB and :OnBeforeNavigate2 to open URL in another browser

Tags: delphi

I need to open another browser sometimes if users click a link.

I am using CHtmlView::OnBeforeNavigate2 to cancel the integrated web browser from opening the specific URL;  and instead I will open it in another firefox.

However this does not seem to be a good place to do this.
For some reason OnBeforeNavigate is also called, when user does not click a link at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`OnBeforeNavigate2`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/SHDocVw.TWebBrowser.OnBeforeNavigate2) event is the best place to cancel the ongoing navigation. Just, if you want to detect if this event was triggered by a hyperlink click (since it fires e.g. for frames when they are loaded), you can determine if the `Flags` parameter contains the [`navHyperlink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx) value, like this e.g.:

```
procedure TForm1.WebBrowser1BeforeNavigate2(ASender: TObject;
  const pDisp: IDispatch; const URL, Flags, TargetFrameName, PostData,
  Headers: OleVariant; var Cancel: WordBool);
begin
  if ((Flags and navHyperlink) <> 0) and (URL = 'http://example.com') then
  begin
    Cancel := True;
    // the user clicked a link to http://example.com and the navigation is
    // going to be cancelled; now do whatever else you need here
  end;
end;
```

I cannot tell you which versions of Internet Explorer passes this value, but I can tell you for sure, that the MSDN documentation for web browser is almost completely outdated.

Comment: Thanks, what is the value of navHyperlink  - my Delphi does not have that defined

Comment: Define it as `const navHyperlink = $40;`, it is from the [`BrowserNavConstants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768360(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration. Well, the [`BeforeNavigate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768280(v=vs.85).aspx) event should use the [`BrowserBeforeNavConstants`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768359(v=vs.85).aspx) enumeration for its flags, but it obviously doesn't. So this is actually undocumented, but I think it's just because the docs are outdated.