# TWebBrowser: Get link href when I click in image with link

Tags: html, image, delphi, twebbrowser

I need to get a link that is associated with an image.
As you can see in the code below, I have a customization of the TWebBrowser component. I intercept the mouse click on the WebBrowser view.

The current code works fine for common links, however for the case of the image I'm not able to get the href link when I click on the image.

When I click in image, I have get link href="https://vimeo.com/194387045"

Any other way I can go?

```html
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/194387045" target="_blank">
<img src="http://172.16.0.16/static/comunica/436dde8236d078cff2dc76deaa113dbb" 
alt="" /></a></p>
```

**Method:**

```
Procedure TJBWebBrowser.ValidateLinkClick;
Var
  LElement: IHTMLElement;
  LLink, LTag: String;
  LCancel: Boolean;
  LDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
Begin

  LDocument := IHTMLDocument2(Document);

  If Not Assigned(LDocument) Then
    Exit;

  LCancel := False;
  LElement := LDocument.parentWindow.event.srcElement;
  LTag := Trim(LowerCase(LElemento.tagName));

  If LTag = 'a' Then
    LLink := Trim(LElement.getAttribute('href', 0));

  If Assigned(FOnURLClick) Then
    FOnURLClick(Self, LLink, LCancel);

  If (LLink <> EmptyStr) And (Not LCancel) Then
    ShellExecute(0, Nil, PChar(LLink), Nil, Nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
End;
```

Comment: So, you are saying that the `srcElement` is the actual `<img>` itself, rather than the `<a>` that the `<img>` is contained inside of?  I would have expected the `<a>` tag to be the `srcElement`. The real question is, why are you handling HTML events like this in the first place, instead of using the browser's own `OnBeforeNavigate2` event instead? It gives you the URL being navigated to, and the option to cancel the navigation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I've implemented a process to capture the clicked link in the browser. The OnBeforeNavegate2 event provides the URL in navigation, for example, WebBrowser1.Navegate ('https://www.google.com'). In this case, OnBeforeNavegate2 is executed if the Navegate method is called. It is not my case. I have an HTML that I set to the Browser and I need to validate the link that the user clicked on. In my sample, when I click in image, the URL returned is http://172.16.0.16/static/comunica/436dde8236d078cff2dc76deaa113dbb. But I need to return https://vimeo.com/194387045

Comment: @Delphiman, No. The `OnBeforeNavigate2` is fired each time you click a link and navigate to a URL. see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25311587/937125

Comment: @kobik, You're right. I forgot to mention that I use TWebBrowser more as an html editor, in case I step into it an Html ready with links.
Example: WebBrowser1.Document.body.innerHTML: = 'my html';

In this case, when I use direct assignment of Htmls the OnBeforeNavegate2 event is not triggered. This event will only work if I'm browsing some page, in this case, using the Navegate method. So I needed to create a mechanism to validate links. Below, I have an example showing the situation.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5LYCu1APjPsUlZjSGlDZGV2b1U/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my doubt.

Thanks for everyone's help.

Follow the changed code:

```
Procedure TJBWebBrowser.ValidateLinkClick;
Var
  LElement: IHTMLElement;
  LLink, LTag: String;
  LCancel: Boolean;
  LDocument: IHTMLDocument2;
Begin

  LCancel := False;
  LDocument := IHTMLDocument2(Document);

  If Not Assigned(LDocument) Then
    Exit;

  //Old line
  //LElement := LDocument.parentWindow.event.srcElement;

  //New line
  LElement := LDocument.activeElement;
  if not Assigned(LElement) then
    Exit;

  LTag := Trim(LowerCase(LElement.tagName));

  If LTag = 'a' Then
    LLink := Trim(LElement.getAttribute('href', 0));

  If Assigned(FOnURLClick) Then
    FOnURLClick(Self, LLink, LCancel);

  If (LLink <> EmptyStr) And (Not LCancel) Then
    ShellExecute(0, Nil, PChar(LLink), Nil, Nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
End;
```